# Add numeration in columns sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following chart:

[image]

I wonder if there is any way to make a query, I would like to add a numbering as shown in the following example.
[image]

The columns of my table (fechaSuspencion, plazoSuspencion, fechaTerminacion)
a number that is added increases.

He did not know what title is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER windowing function.  Sample code below:

```
declare @test  table (fechaSuspencion datetime, plazoSuspencion varchar(50), fechaTerminacion datetime)
insert into @test values ('20161212', '5 meses', '20160112')
select 
    'fechaSuspencion' + ltrim(rtrim(str(row_number() over (order by fechaSuspencion)))) as fsnumber
    ,fechaSuspencion
    ,'plazoSuspencion' + ltrim(rtrim(str(row_number() over (order by fechaSuspencion)))) as psnumber
    ,plazoSuspencion
    ,'fechaTerminacion' + ltrim(rtrim(str(row_number() over (order by fechaSuspencion)))) as psnumber
    ,fechaTerminacion
from
    @test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms186734.aspx) functionality:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY fechaSuspencion, plazoSuspencion, fechaTerminacion) AS Row, *   
FROM [TABLE_NAME]
```